# how to pass parameters from an aws event to a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

say, I want to run a lambda via some trigger, cloudwatch event in this case. is it possible to pass a parameter to this lambda via cloudwatch event trigger. my lambda code is in python and depending up a command line argument , i pass via command line . it proceses the data, it works locally but if i made this to a lambda and hook it up to an cloudwatch event , how can i pass those parameters that i pass it via commandline. I can run this on an ec2 instance as well, like a fargate task. how can i pass those arugments when this code is triggered via an event?

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    aws_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Get our parameter
    //read paarameter 

   ...
```

Comment: What's triggering the event?

Comment: doesn't cloudwatch trigger it? i was planning to make it like a cron job

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup `input template` for the target, as explained in the docs: [Tutorial: Use Input Transformer to Customize What is Passed to the Event Target - Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html)

Comment: thanks. i will go through the link you provided. any working examples you know may be in terraform or cloudformation

Comment: @ozil In terraform use [input_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#input_template).

Comment: thanks again. any chance that you know of a sample cloudformation template

Comment: @ozil Please try writing it yourself, and make new question if you get stack.